# Intellij IDEA - Webservices client from WSDL with certificates

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, intellij-idea

I am somewhat new to SSL/TLS and Java trust/keystores. I am attempting to generate a client to consume a web service from a IIS-hosted WSDL file. This worked fine before the service was configured to require certificates. I now receive a `Wsdl url connection exception`.

In an attempt to bypass this, I saved a local copy of the WSDL via IE (with the appropriate certs in place via the Certificates MMC snap-in). I then attempted to point IDEA to that location (`file:/C:/projects/wsdl/wsdlname.wsdl`).

This fails with the following error messages:

```
parsing WSDL...

[ERROR] sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid
certification path to requested target unknown location

[ERROR] invalid entity name: "Auth" (in namespace: "******")
line 0 of unknown location
```

Note: I've starred out the namespace.

1. Is there a way to configure IntelliJ IDEA to be able to present a valid certificate if I want to use the generation utility/wizard?
2. Is there a potential issue with the web service that is causing even the local WSDL import to fail?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should help if you install the certificate into JVM that is used to run IDEA via `keytool`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So I assume I need to import my CA certs into `JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts`. With respect to my client certificates that need to be provided to the web service, how do I go about configuring the JVM/IntelliJ IDEA to provide these?

Comment: You either import them into JRE under IDEA_HOME or you configure IDEA to run under different JDK with the certificate already imported: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/08/running-mustang/.